# Change the background colour of photoswipe

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, photoswipe

http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html
I'm using this example. I've for ages but have no idea where the background colour is.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Please explain more clearly, give your code not a link to your plugin.

Answer (score 4):

It is now in **photoswipe.css** file - see 'background' property of the class:

**.pswp__bg**

You may change it to whatever color you need.

Answer (score 3):

In the docs. Set bgOpacity to 0.85 for example.

http://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html

```
var options = {  index: 0, bgOpacity: 0.85 };
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Cargo Collective to build a site, and their built-in lightbox uses photoswipe. I had to add the following to the custom CSS to change the background color:

```
}
.pswp__bg {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
.Pswp_bg image-zoom-background {
    background-color: #fff !important;
```